# Grails Security: how to preprocess username (to make it case-insensitive)?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

The default implementation of Spring Security treats the username as case-sensitive, I need to make it case-insensitive for usability reasons (one major reasons is users with mobile devices whose default behavior is to capitalize the first letter of an input text). This is a business requirement.

By the time control is passed to the LoginController generated by the plugin, it's too late: Spring Security has already determined the login failed. With a debugger I can see the flow passes through `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#attemptAuthentication` but I don't know how to intervene from Grails. In fact, the plugin uses a subclass, `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter`, but that's inside the plugin source, not my application, so I don't know where to intervene.

Any pointers are appreciated. 
Thank you.

Environment: Grails 2.3, Spring Security Plugin 1.2.7.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a custom `UserDetailsService` - see https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#userDetailsService

```
package com.yourcompany.yourapp

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserDetailsService
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException

class MyUserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService {

   static final List NO_ROLES = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]

   UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
      User.withTransaction { status ->
         User user = User.findByUsernameIlike(username)
         if (!user) throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)

         def authorities = user.authorities.collect { new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority) }

         new GrailsUser(user.username, user.password, user.enabled, !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired,
            !user.accountLocked, authorities ?: NO_ROLES, user.id)
      }
   }

   UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
      loadUserByUsername username
   }
}
```

Register this in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy to override the plugin's implementation:

```
beans = {
   userDetailsService(com.yourcompany.yourapp.MyUserDetailsService)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I extended GormUserDetailsService and overrode loadUserByUsername(username) to call super.loadUserByUsername(username.toLowerCase()) and it does so. Surprisingly, it fails inside org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GormUserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername at the line: def dc = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(userClassName) with org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
DUMMY.groovy: 1: unexpected token: = @ line 1, column 64.
   Closure _JETGROOVY_EVAL_ = {->= grailsAp
                                 ^
1 error
I'm puzzled...

Comment: The previous exception appears in the debugger. In the server log there's just java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getDomainClass() on null object
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GormUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:52)
 at my.app.UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsService.groovy)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GormUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:77)  which is odd, as userClassName is correctly set to "my.app.SpringUser" (as before)

Comment: Already have the properties defined in Config.groovy: `grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'my.appSpringUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'my.appSpringUserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'my.appRole'`

Comment: Digging, `grailsApplication` is null inside `GormUserDetailsService`.

Comment: Hmm.. found that `userDetailsService(com.yourcompany.yourapp.MyUserDetailsService)` causes grailsApplication to be not injected. But then the custom service is, of course, not called either.

Comment: Try the version in my answer, updated to use your domain classes. It's a lot simpler than the plugin's, which is very complicated because it supports customized class and property names. But when you're doing your own, it's a lot cleaner to just use your real classes.

If you want to subclass the plugin's impl, register it like this:

```beans = {
   userDetailsService(com.yourcompany.yourapp.MyUserDetailsService) {
      grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
   }
}```

Comment: Ah, I just came in to say I found it as well, I added `   bean.autowire = 'byName'` for the bean's closure(I found a message from 2011 on a mailing list where you were asking why resources are not injected :-). All is well now. Thank you sir and thank you for the plugin!

Comment: For reference of those who are looking to implement this in their own app, I needed to change the User class (line 15 of Burt's code) to reference my own MyUser class (domain\com.myapp\MyUser).

Comment: Similar solution found here http://www.stevideter.com/2012/11/17/case-insensitive-usernames-using-spring-security-core-plugin-for-grails/ has worked for me.